# Vuetify issue: how to show a image to enable "save image as" on the user browser?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've a vuejs application using `<v-img>` to show an image to user but when image is showed on the browser and I use the right mouse button to get options, I don't see the option to save image on my computer or cell phone. How I can show the image to user easyliest save image on your device?

Actually, I've saved the images on the Firebase and show with the path.

```html
 <v-dialog v-model="showReceiptDialog" max-width="90%" max-height="90%">
      <v-img align="center" :src="urlReceiptFile" v-on:error="onImgError">
        <v-btn style="left: 0px; position: fixed;" @click="showReceiptDialog = false">
          <v-icon>close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-img>
    </v-dialog>
```

Actual behavior:
[image]

Comment: As I suspected the image is shown as `background-image`, if you want the user to be able to save it, you need a regular `<img>`.

Comment: i've changed do <img>. Problem solved. thanks.